# Searching a SQL database by 'date'

Tags: sql, vb.net, date

I'm trying to search a SQL database using this SQL query:

> SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate=06/12/13

Here is an image of my SQL Reservations table with dummy data:

[image: Data]

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
C.

Comment: To be more certain - use `'2013-12-06'` as format, and remember the ' - or use a variable of the appropriate datatype

Comment: put a quote round the date like '06/12/13'

Comment: I now get an error telling me there's a 'Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression', but it's a step forward!

Comment: What step forward do you mean? what did you run?

Comment: I edited my SQL query appropriately and ran it, it's a different error message. :)

Comment: what is the command you ran from the suggestions so far?

Comment: My new SQL query which I ran just now was 'SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate='06/12/13''

Comment: see what you did, one single opening quote and closing it with double quote

Comment: No no, sorry, that was deliberate, because I put the whole command in ''.

Comment: The literal command is: SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate='06/12/13'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing date format from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'yyyy/mm/dd'.

Like this:

SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate='2013/11/08'

See sample [SQL Fiddle I created](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0798a26/1)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put the date inside ''

```
SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate='06/12/13'
```

But, if what you're showing us a view, then you'll need to use the standard format for dates:

```
SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate='2013-12-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quotes around the date `''`

It should be simply:

```
SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate = '06/12/13'
```

Comment: I now get an error telling me there's a 'Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression', but it's a step forward!

Comment: @user7378 How you executing it?? Can you please provide the complete line the way you ran it.??

Comment: As this: SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate='08/11/2013'

Comment: try running the command without the where statement like this: **SELECT * FROM Reservations**

Comment: This gives me everything in the database. :)

Comment: The 'WHERE' works for every field, apart from the date field from testing it out.

Comment: Try with `SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE fDate = '06/12/2013'`

Comment: having space bw the equals won't make any difference. I think the column fDate data type is incorrect

Comment: can you confirm the Data Type for the column fDate by checking the properties of the column fDate and see what the Data Type was set to

Comment: Just recreated the whole field, including the dummy data. Same error. Data type is 'Date and Time'.

Comment: what version of SQL is this?

Comment: 2007-2010, according to the title bar.

Comment: what title bar :), just run select @@VERSION create a chat for this

Comment: Try putting square brackets around the date field as: `[fDate] = '06/12/2013'`

Comment: Fixed it now by designing the query in the 'design' view.

Comment: > SELECT * FROM Reservations WHERE (((Reservations.fDate)=#12/6/2013#))

Thanks to everyone that helped.